# How to vectorized version of this code using np.meshgrid and np.linspace

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, linspace

How can I write a vectorized version of this code cell below? The code should be fully vectorized, with no for-loops, using np.meshgrid and np.linspace?

```
def eval_on_grid_unvectorized(func, extent, numsteps):


     """Evaluates func(x1, x2) for each combination in a 2D grid.

    func: callable - function to evaluate for each grid element

    extent: tuple - grid extent as (x1min, x1max, x2min, x2max)

    numsteps: int - number of grid steps (same for each 
    dimension)

    """
    x1min, x1max, x2min, x2max = extent

    x1 = np.empty((numsteps, numsteps))
    x2 = np.empty((numsteps, numsteps))
    y  = np.empty((numsteps, numsteps))
    for i in range(numsteps):
        for j in range(numsteps):
           x1[i,j] = x1min + j*(x1max-x1min)/(numsteps-1)
           x2[i,j] = x2min + i*(x2max-x2min)/(numsteps-1)
           y[i,j] = func(x1[i,j], x2[i,j])
    return x1, x2, y
```

Comment: This is not possible to efficiently vectorize arbitrary `func` function with Numpy. Numpy provides function to vectorize functions from the user point of view but they are inefficient since they just do a naive loop internally. Thus, you need to provide the code of `func`. If `func` is a generic function and you cannot specialize this code nor the one of `func`, then there is no way to vectorize the function (at least with Numpy).

Comment: Thanks Richard! func is a lambda function. See below where eval_on_grid_unvectorized is called :


x1, x2, y = eval_on_grid_unvectorized(lambda x1, x2: x1 + x2, (-1, 1, 0, 2), 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, without the `y`; produces

```
In [57]: eval_on_grid_unvectorized(None,(0,5,0,6),6)
Out[57]: 
(array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]]),
 array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
        [2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4],
        [3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6],
        [4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8],
        [6. , 6. , 6. , 6. , 6. , 6. ]]))
```

Meshgrid and linspace can do the same:

```
In [59]: np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,5,6), np.linspace(0,6,6),indexing='xy')
Out[59]: 
[array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]]),
 array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
        [2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4],
        [3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6],
        [4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8],
        [6. , 6. , 6. , 6. , 6. , 6. ]])]
```

But as Jérôme points out, as long as `func` can only work with scalar values, you can't "vectorize", in the sense of doing fast whole array calculations.

If the func is something like `x+y`, then we can simply pass the arrays to it:

```
In [60]: _[0]+_[1]
Out[60]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ],
       [ 1.2,  2.2,  3.2,  4.2,  5.2,  6.2],
       [ 2.4,  3.4,  4.4,  5.4,  6.4,  7.4],
       [ 3.6,  4.6,  5.6,  6.6,  7.6,  8.6],
       [ 4.8,  5.8,  6.8,  7.8,  8.8,  9.8],
       [ 6. ,  7. ,  8. ,  9. , 10. , 11. ]])
```

The key to what we normally call `vectorization` in `numpy` is to write the calculation in a way that uses the compiled numpy methods, and operators.  It requires real knowledge of `numpy`; there isn't a magic short cut to let you jump from scalar Python calculations to efficient `numpy` ones.